# How to specify a default value in a JSON API Response for Jackson Retrofit Android parsing?

Tags: android, jackson, retrofit2

I have a class declared like:

```
public class Doc {
    private final String mTitle;
    private final String mCanRespond;

    @JsonCreator
    public Doc(@JsonProperty("title") final String title, @JsonProperty("can_respond") final boolean canRespond) {
       mTitle = title;
       mCanRespond = canRespond;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to specify the default value of `mCanRespond` as `true` if the field `can_respond` is missing from the JSON response. 
Current behavior is if it is missing, the value of `canRespond` is `false`.

I tried using the `Boolean` object, but it doesn't get assigned `null` either.

Comment: I know how to do the same with GSON but not with Jackson :(

Comment: @Code_Life how do you do it with GSON?

Answer (score 3):

For GSON , to do similar kind of functionality , just initialise the parameter in default constructor. So if any key is missing from JSON response its default value will be set .